# Compiling lua for arm: dlfcn.h missing

Tags: c++, gcc, lua, linker

I am trying to compile lua for an arm processor. I adapted the lua makefile to make it use arm-none-eabi-gcc. I dont think the details of lua are relevant, but my flags are visible in the following error message. When I try to compile it I get the following error:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -O2 -Wall -Wextra -DLUA_COMPAT_5_2 -DLUA_USE_LINUX -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -gdwarf-2 -mthumb -g3   -c -o loadlib.o loadlib.c
loadlib.c:107:19: fatal error: dlfcn.h: No such file or directory
#include <dlfcn.h>
```

Can someone help me how I fix this? I went through many different sites and installed lots of random packages, but I have no idea where I should get the file dlfcn.h from.
I installed gcc-arm-none-eabi using apt and also tried installing the latest version as stated in this question from [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1243252/how-to-install-arm-none-eabi-gdb-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts-focal-fossa?newreg=a9aec80d6d274de6a8e1a1b7c0901a24) below. Nothing seems to work. I dont even have an idea where to look for a solution.

Comment: Try `make clean posix` instead. That should give you Lua without support for dynamic libraries.

Comment: @lhf How does this help me get my program to arm? (sorry if this might sound stupid) In the end I want to compile a program for arm processor and when I compile my c code for arm then I cant link it with lua. If I try to I get `lua-5.4.4/src//liblua.a: error adding symbols: File format not recognized` (which is probably the case because liblua.a was built for another architecture if I am not mistaken)

Comment: It would remove dynamic library load (and dlfcn.h) as a dependency, thus allowing your build to proceed. As to the liblua.a error, you should be building liblua.a as part of the same `make` command, so there shouldn't be any architecture mismatch.

Comment: So if I understand correctly I have to use arm-none-eabi-gcc as compiler when doing `make posix`. If I do this though, I get a lot of undefined references. I can fix some of them by using `--specs=nosys.specs`, but I still have for example:
lua-5.4.4/src/lua.c:50: undefined reference to sigaction
lua-5.4.4/src/lua.c:50: undefined reference to sigaction
lua-5.4.4/src/lua.c:50: undefined reference to sigaction
liblua.a(ldo.o): In function luaD_throw:
lua-5.4.4/src/ldo.c:118: undefined reference to _longjmp
liblua.a(ldo.o): In function luaD_rawrunprotected:

Comment: If `make posix` does not work, try `make generic` or `make c89`.